# ForEach element in layout or screen

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have been trying to hack a foreach to all elements of type label in screen or layout, with no luck!
My goal is to translate all screen1.labels.text, the translation are in list which has lists of pair (label.text, translation).
Is this possible in App-inventor?

Comment: I just found this solution, but I would like to do without having to add all elements in separated list. https://amerkashi.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/anycomponent/

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought of getting an array list of sub view and iterating thought them. the below will work for direct children of the screen. if you need sub view as well you can use recursion

```
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_screen_to_search);
 for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) 
 {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if(child instanceOf TextView)
    {
        txtView = (TextView)child;
        if(txtView.getText().length!=0)
        {
            yourTranslateFunction(txtView.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am expecting App-Inventor answer!

Comment: Oh sorry, I cant help with that